# How to send data object from controller to view using jquery ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

> What wrong send data from controller to view

Comment: Clearly `Unclear` what you are asking

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Answer (score -2):

In controller you can pass data as JSON format and in view through Ajax request you can fetch that data.

For example, here is my activity method in controller

```
Public function activity(){
  $data = [ 'name' => 'Jenny', 'age' => 11 ];  header('Content-type: application/json'); return json_encode( $data );    
}
```

In ajax request you can get data in success response as

```
$.ajax({
  .....
  Success(data){
    data.responseJson.name //this will return Jenny
  }  
}
```

Comment: Downvoting as this is simply a wild stab in the dark to a clearly unanswerable question